# How to dynamically add a key/value pair to a nested JavaScript object?

Tags: javascript

I have this object below and i want to add key/value pairs i had some tries which i supposed it should work because it has worked before in some cases but to my suprise it didn't work. below is my object

```
{
 "696770849122": 
    {
         "min_num": 2,
         "nick": "绵米兔批发",
         "orginal_price": 23, 
         "post_fee": 4, 
         "price": 23,
         "sku": [[Object], [Object]], 
         "title": "街舞小众设计灰色运动裤女宽松阔腿美式 嘻哈卫裤爵士舞jazz长裤",

    }, 
 "727870247137":
    {

         "min_num": 2,
         "nick": "绵米兔批发",
         "orginal_price": 25, 
         "post_fee": 4, 
         "price": 25,
         "title": "白色龙字母长裤女2023春季新款女街头时尚嘻哈hiphop跳舞运动裤潮", 


     }
 }
```

I wanted to dynamically add some other key to the object so i want my new object to look like

i will dynamically add `remark` and `receiver_address_id` as such

```
 {
 "696770849122": 
    {
         "min_num": 2,
         "nick": "绵米兔批发",
         "orginal_price": 23, 
         "post_fee": 4, 
         "price": 23,
         "sku": [[Object], [Object]], 
         "title": "街舞小众设计灰色运动裤女宽松阔腿美式 嘻哈卫裤爵士舞jazz长裤",
         "remark": 'welcome to my word',
         "receiver_address_id": 25

    }, 
 "727870247137":
    {

         "min_num": 2,
         "nick": "绵米兔批发",
         "orginal_price": 25, 
         "post_fee": 4, 
         "price": 25,
         "title": "白色龙字母长裤女2023春季新款女街头时尚嘻哈hiphop跳舞运动裤潮", 
         "remark": 'hello world',
         "receiver_address_id": 23


     }
 }
```

Below is what i tried so far

```
 Object.keys(order).forEach( function(key) {
        order[key]['remark'] = dynamic value;
        order[key]['receiver_address_id'] = dynamic value;
    
    })

 console.log(order) //got the original object back no changes occured
 console.log(order[key].remark) // undefined
 console.log(order[key].receiver_address_id) // undefined
 console.log(order[key]['remark']) // undefined
 console.log(order[key]['receiver_address_id']) // undefined
```

what am I doing wrong while is the original object not updated and why the new key have undefined value?

Comment: Your `console.log()` calls are outside the loop, so there's no `key` variable.

Comment: Please show a full reproducible example (you can use the `<>` snippet button so we can actually see it happening live within the question post itself). From what you show, it's not clear what's happening., as you seem to be logging _some_ `key`'s properties, however we don't know where that variable came from. (By the way, `x.y` and `x['y']` are the same thing, no need to try both.)

Comment: for the full picture, `console.log({ order, key })`.  Also, if `key` is undefined then `order[key].remark` should say `Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'remark')` which actually means that `order[key]` is undefined. not that `order[key].remark` is undefined.  If `order[key]` is undefined then the `key` is likely wrong because there is no property of the order with that key or `key` itself is `undefined`...which is different from being _not defined_: look for `ReferenceError: key is not defined`

Comment: I used your obj as base and the code you tried actually works, which means the problem is elsewhere. Just try with a fixed string as values.

Comment: @RudyMartin yeah you're right because the code is working inside snippest